# Save PowerPoint 2007 as PowerPoint 2003 using Open Office SDK 2.0

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there anyway to use the Open Office SDK 2.0 to save a PowerPoint presention that you created using OOXML to a PowerPoint 2003 presentation?  I know if you open a 2007 file and click Save As you have the option to save it as a PowerPoint 97 to 2003 document and I didn't know if I could do this grammatically using this SDK.

The reason I am asking this question is because I need to give the user the option to save data on a website in either Office 2007 or 2003 format.  I much rather just use the same code to produce the document instead of having to have two code paths for PowerPoint 2003 and PowerPoint 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Open Office SDK 2.0 is built for and around System.IO.Packaging to work with the Open Document Format (the zip package that wraps up all the xml and other files for Office 2007, XPS, etc.) in processing the ECMA/ISO standard for Office 2007/2010 formats.

Comment: Yeah that is what I figured the answer would be.